# Tensorflow Object Detection API w/ TPU Training - Display more granular Tensorboard plots

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api, google-cloud-tpu

I've been following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193) on the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), and I've successfully trained my own object detection model using Google's Cloud TPUs.

However, the problem is that on Tensorboard, the plots I'm seeing only have 2 data points each (so it just plots a straight line), like this:
[image]

...whereas I want to see more "granular" plots like these below, which are much more detailed:

[image]

[The tutorial I've been following](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193) acknowledges that this issue is caused by the fact that TPU training requires very few steps to train:

> Note that these graphs only have 2 points plotted since the model
>   trains quickly in very few steps (if you’ve used TensorBoard before
>   you may be used to seeing more of a curve here)

I tried adding `save_checkpoints_steps=50` in the file `model_tpu_main.py` (see code fragment below), and when I re-ran training, I was able to get a more granular plot, with 1 data point every 300 steps or so.

```
config = tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig(
      # I added this line below:
      save_checkpoints_steps=50,

      master=tpu_grpc_url,
      evaluation_master=tpu_grpc_url,
      model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
      tpu_config=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUConfig(
          iterations_per_loop=FLAGS.iterations_per_loop,
          num_shards=FLAGS.num_shards))
```

[image]

However, my training job is actually saving a checkpoint every 100 steps, rather than every 300 steps. Looking at the logs, my evaluation job is running every 300 steps. Is there a way I can make my evaluation job run every 100 steps (whenever there's a new checkpoint) so that I can get more granular plots on Tensorboard?

Answer (score 1):

Code which addresses this issue is explained by a technical lead for the Google cloud platform in a [Medium blogpost](https://medium.com/tensorflow/how-to-write-a-custom-estimator-model-for-the-cloud-tpu-7d8bd9068c26). Alternatively go directly to the [Github code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/08_image/flowersmodeltpu).

The [train_and_evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/08_image/flowersmodeltpu/model.py) function of 81 lines defines an `TPUEstimator`, `train_input_fn` and `eval_input_fn`. Then it iterates to the training steps and calls `estimator.train` and `estimator.evaluate` in each iteration. The metrics can be defined in the `model_fn`, which is called [image_classifier](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/08_image/flowersmodeltpu/model.py). Note that it currently has no effect to add `tf.summary` calls in the model functions since the TPU does not support it:

*"TensorBoard summaries are a great way see inside your model. A minimal set of basic summaries are automatically recorded by the TPUEstimator, to event files in the model_dir. Custom summaries, however, are currently unsupported when training on a Cloud TPU. So while the TPUEstimator will still run locally with summaries, it will fail if used on a TPU."* [(source)](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_tpu)

If summaries are important it might be more convenient to switch to training on GPU.

Personally I think writing this code is quite a hassle for something which should be handled by the API. Please update this answer if better solutions exist! I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I'm still a beginner at Tensorflow so I didn't entirely understand what you were talking about, and also I'm not too bothered to solve this issue for now, but I hope that other people can upvote your answer if they find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Set save_summary_steps in RunConfig to 100, so you get the statistics you want
Also iterations_per_loop to 100 so that the training doesn't go more steps

p.s. I hope you realize that checkpointing is very slow. You are probably raising the cost of your job just for the sake of a pretty graph :)

Comment: `save_summary_steps` and `iterations_per_loop` were both already set to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `throttle_secs=100` to the EvalSpecs constructor [here](https://github.com/pkulzc/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib.py#L609). The default is 600 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and get back to you later.

Comment: I tried `throttle_secs=100` and it didn't work (my evaluation job still performs an evaluation every 300 steps). However I'll try a lower value like `throttle_secs=60` and let you know the result.

Comment: Could you try also adding save_checkpoints_secs=100 keyword argument to RunConfig here;https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py#L55

Comment: It's already using `save_checkpoints_steps=50` (though it's `steps` instead of `secs`)

Comment: Also I tried `throttle_secs=60` and the evaluation job still performs an evaluation every 300 steps